# Instantiate function for all combinations of template params, choose instantation at run time

Tags: c++, templates

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find this exact question.

I have a templated CUDA kernel that looks like this:

```
template<int firstTextureIndex, int secondTextureIndex, int thirdTextureIndex> __global__ void myKernel
```

The three texture index template types will range from 0-7 and will not be known until runtime. I need to instantiate all 512 combinations of this kernel and then call the correct template based on the runtime values of the texture indices.

I've never written any pre processing macros and am trying to avoid it. Another post, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774882/c-instantiate-templates-in-loop), shows how to instantiate many *class* templates for one template variable recursively by doing this:

```
template<int i>
class loop {
    loop<i-1> x;
}

template<>
class loop<1> {
}

loop<10> l;
```

I'm struggling to extend that to 3 variables and a function (instead of a class) for my situation. Even if I figure out how to instantiate all of them that way, how do I actually call 1 out of 512 possibilities at runtime without nested switch statements? To illustrate, the nested switch statements I'm trying to avoid would be like:

```
switch(firstTextureIndex)
{
    case 0:
        switch(secondTextureIndex)
        {
            case 1:
                switch(thirdTextureIndex)
                {
                    case 2:
                        myKernel<0, 1, 2><<<grid, block>>>(param1, param2, param3);
                        break;
                }
             break;
        }
    break;
}
```

If I figure out how to instantiate 0-7 for all of them, could I call it like:

```
myKernel<i, j, k><<<grid, block>>>(param1, param2);
```

if I make i, j, and k enum types containing only 0-7? This way the compiler could know all the possible values and since I instantiate them all it would be OK with it?

Please note that there are good reasons for this triple template to pass in texture indices, but I'm omitting the explanation for conciseness. Any help on instantiating and/or calling this kernel would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Jarod42 provided a valid solution that does exactly what I asked. Unfortunately I now realize the c++ standard is important here. I'm using c++98/03 combined with the latest stable release of the boost library, so a solution using these would be ideal. I could potentially use c++11, but c++14 is out due to limitations of our compiler.

Comment: With `firstTextureIndex * 64 + secondTextureIndex * 8 + thirdTextureIndex`, you may restrict to one variable.

Comment: Nice idea! That would actually work for me and simplifies the problem a decent amount. I still need to select 1/512 possibilities at runtime and instantiate all those, but at least it can be condensed to one variable.

Comment: Please consider dropping the CUDA references - as your question and the answers don't actually have anything to do with CUDA. Just have a dummy function like in @havogt's example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is an implementation for **C++98/03** and **boost.MPL**. There is definitely room for improvement (for example hiding the global pointer array, checking for illegal combinations, ...).

The idea is to recursively run through all combinations of the integer lists and thereby fill an array of function pointers for each combination.

I used a similar, more complex code before for selecting at run time the best combination of kernel parameters (auto tuning) like `launch_bounds` and other options: [culgt/runtimechooser](https://github.com/culgt/runtimechooser).

Here is a simplified version for your case

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

template<int index1, int index2, int index3> void execKernel()
{
    std::cout << "Kernel called with " << index1 << "/" << index2 << "/" << index3 << std::endl;
}

typedef void (*FPTR)();
FPTR ptr[512];

struct NIL
{
public:
    static const int value = 0;
};

template<typename Seq, typename T1, typename T2 = NIL> class MakeSequenceImpl
{
public:
    template<typename T> void operator()(T)
    {
        typedef MakeSequenceImpl<typename mpl::push_back<Seq,T>::type,T2> RunSeq;
        mpl::for_each<T1>( RunSeq() );
    }
};

template<typename Seq> class MakeSequenceImpl<Seq, NIL, NIL>
{
public:
    template<typename T> void operator()(T)
    {
        typedef typename mpl::push_back<Seq,T>::type FinalSeq;

        int index = mpl::at<FinalSeq,mpl::int_<0> >::type::value * 64
                + mpl::at<FinalSeq,mpl::int_<1> >::type::value * 8
                + mpl::at<FinalSeq,mpl::int_<2> >::type::value;

        ptr[index] = execKernel<mpl::at<FinalSeq,mpl::int_<0> >::type::value, mpl::at<FinalSeq,mpl::int_<1> >::type::value, mpl::at<FinalSeq,mpl::int_<2> >::type::value>;
    }
};


template<typename T0, typename T1, typename T2> class MakeSequence
{
public:
    typedef mpl::vector_c<int> Seq;

    MakeSequence()
    {
        typedef MakeSequenceImpl<Seq, T1, T2> RunSeq;
        mpl::for_each<T0>( RunSeq() );
    }
};


void callWrapper( int i, int j, int k )
{
    ptr[i*64+j*8+k]();
}

typedef mpl::vector_c< int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 > list1;
typedef mpl::vector_c< int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 > list2;
typedef mpl::vector_c< int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 > list3;

int main()
{
    MakeSequence<list1,list2,list3> frontend;

    int i,j,k;

    std::cin >> i;
    std::cin >> j;
    std::cin >> k;

    callWrapper(i,j,k);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may do something like:

```
template <std::size_t I>
void do_job()
{
    myKernel<I / 64, (I / 8) % 8, I % 8>{}();
}

template <std::size_t ... Is>
void callMyKernel(std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t k)
{
    std::function<void()> fs[] = {&do_job<Is>...};

    fs[i * 64 + j * 8 + k]();
}

void callMyKernel(std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t k)
{
    callMyKernel(std::make_index_sequence<512>{}, i, j, k);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/zW5gWk)

Comment: Thanks! That's a really great solution and I learned a lot from your Demo. Unfortunately I only have access to c++99, but at least I have access to the latest stable release of the boost library. I could maybe convince coworkers to upgrade to c++11, but our OS compiler does not support c++14. 

I will continue to search for a solution myself using at most c++11, but you clearly have a more complete understanding of polymorphism than I do. Any ideas for a solution using c++99 with boost (ideally) or c++11 with boost? I will edit my question to include this relevant info.

Comment: `index_sequence` stuff may be done in C++11 (but not in C++03).

Comment: I wish I could mark you both correct. I'm going with the solution from @havogt because I can use it without changing the c++ standard we use. You 100% answered the original question correctly though and it's my bad for not mentioning the standard.