# Generalizing Solution To Instantiate Many Templates of a Function And Select At Runtime

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I'm trying to generalize a solution previously provided on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562342/instantiate-many-templates-of-a-function-and-select-template-at-run-time-c-cud), which uses boost MPL to instantiate many templates of a function and select the correct one at runtime. The information I need is likely spread around the internet, but I'm struggling to piece together a working solution myself. Here is a copy paste of the previous solution for readability:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

template<int index1, int index2, int index3> void execKernel()
{
    std::cout << "Kernel called with " << index1 << "/" << index2 << "/" << index3 << std::endl;
}

typedef void (*FPTR)();
FPTR ptr[512];

struct NIL
{
public:
    static const int value = 0;
};

template<typename Seq, typename T1, typename T2 = NIL> class MakeSequenceImpl
{
public:
    template<typename T> void operator()(T)
    {
        typedef MakeSequenceImpl<typename mpl::push_back<Seq,T>::type,T2> RunSeq;
        mpl::for_each<T1>( RunSeq() );
    }
};

template<typename Seq> class MakeSequenceImpl<Seq, NIL, NIL>
{
public:
    template<typename T> void operator()(T)
    {
        typedef typename mpl::push_back<Seq,T>::type FinalSeq;

        int index = mpl::at<FinalSeq,mpl::int_<0> >::type::value * 64
                + mpl::at<FinalSeq,mpl::int_<1> >::type::value * 8
                + mpl::at<FinalSeq,mpl::int_<2> >::type::value;

        ptr[index] = execKernel<mpl::at<FinalSeq,mpl::int_<0> >::type::value, mpl::at<FinalSeq,mpl::int_<1> >::type::value, mpl::at<FinalSeq,mpl::int_<2> >::type::value>;
    }
};


template<typename T0, typename T1, typename T2> class MakeSequence
{
public:
    typedef mpl::vector_c<int> Seq;

    MakeSequence()
    {
        typedef MakeSequenceImpl<Seq, T1, T2> RunSeq;
        mpl::for_each<T0>( RunSeq() );
    }
};


void callWrapper( int i, int j, int k )
{
    ptr[i*64+j*8+k]();
}

typedef mpl::vector_c< int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 > list1;
typedef mpl::vector_c< int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 > list2;
typedef mpl::vector_c< int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 > list3;

int main()
{
    MakeSequence<list1,list2,list3> frontend;

    int i,j,k;

    std::cin >> i;
    std::cin >> j;
    std::cin >> k;

    callWrapper(i,j,k);
}
```

I would like to generalize this to pass in "execKernel" as a template parameter to "MakeSequence". I have many functions like "execKernel", all of which take the number of template arguments and same type (all take 3 integer template arguments, 0-7).

To do this, the last line of the operator definition in the final specialization "MakeSequenceImpl< Seq, NIL, NIL>" needs to be generalized on both sides of the equals sign. The left side of that statement is an array of function pointers. The functions I'm trying to generalize this for all take the same template arguments, but different function arguments, so the array of function pointers needs to be passed in somehow. On the right side of the equals sign is the function template instantiation. The specific function template needs to be passed in for this part, but I've discovered you can't pass uninstantiated templated functions as template arguments without using a functor.

To summarize, I'm looking to generalize "MakeSequence" on down such that the array of function pointers and function templates themselves are passed in as arguments. I'm happy to statically define the function pointers and array of function pointers for each specific function. It would be nice to generalize those too (e.g. one big list of function pointers containing all the function pointers for all functions), but this is a secondary issue.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide. BTW, I need to continue working with C++98/03 and boost. No C++11 or 14.

Answer (score 1):

I'd usually think of variants + a visitor:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09d5dc1d1b56675c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

// for demo types
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// some overloads and templates:
template <typename V>
void foo(std::vector<V> const&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 

void foo(int)                   { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
void foo(std::string const&)    { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 

// a generic wrapper that instantiates 3 versions 
// and picks the right one at runtime:
void generic_foo(boost::variant<std::string const&, int, std::vector<double> const&> param) {
    // dispatch
    boost::apply_visitor([](auto&& p) { foo(p); }, param);
}

int main() {
    generic_foo("hello world");
    generic_foo(std::vector<double> {0.1, 0.2, 0.3});
    generic_foo(42);
}
```

Prints

```
void foo(const string&)
void foo(const std::vector<_RealType>&) [with V = double]
void foo(int)
```

### For C++03

Replace the lambda with something a little more verbose:

```
namespace detail {
    struct generic_foo_vis {
        typedef void result_type;
        template <typename T> void operator()(T const& stuff) const { return foo(stuff); }
        template <typename T> void operator()(T& stuff)       const { return foo(stuff); }
    };
}

// a fixed wrapper that instantiates 3 versions and picks the right one at runtime:
void generic_foo(boost::variant<std::string const&, int, std::vector<double> const&> param) {
    // dispatch
    boost::apply_visitor(detail::generic_foo_vis(), param);
}
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45d0871bc8bee759)</kbd>**

Comment: Making a c++03 proof sample. Done: **[c++03 Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45d0871bc8bee759)**

Comment: It will take me a little to digest this and figure out if it's applicable, but one thing that strikes me as noticeably different from the original Q/A is that here the template types are templating the function parameters. In the original Q/A, the template types are not templating the parameters(in fact, I have no templated function parameters). I'm using it for something like myFunction<int i, int j, int k>(unrelated, fun, parameters) where i, j, and k specifically go from 0-7 each.

Comment: Mmm. I did indeed fail to take notice of the sample. You _could_ probably use a similar technique (using std::integral_constant<>) but I'm not sure I'd recommend it. Let me think about it

Comment: Thanks for helping! I'm currently reading about boost variant and visitor as they seem useful to know about in general.